# Open a new URL but in the same tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Hello another time!

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://google.com', '_blank')" />
```

Ok, all of us knows what this code does. It opens a new tab redirecting the person to google.com.

My question is... how can I redirect to a page like google but in the same tab?

I don't want to use the a tag.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use an anchor tag? That's what it is for `<a href="https://google.com">Click</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in HTML: `<a href = "page.html" target = "_self"> </a>`

```html
<button onclick="window.open('https://google.com', '_self')">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe...

```
<button onclick="window.location.replace('https://google.com')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know it 100% sure, but you can always try:

```
window.location="https://google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [window.location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace):

```html
<button onclick="window.location.replace('https://google.com')" >Navigate away in same tab!</button>
```